# Compare results of loop in ListBox

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

Good afternoon,

I'm maintaining an Access database and I have a multiselect and multicolumn listbox on a form. I am querying the listbox to get the values in the third column (containing text) based on all user-selected rows. Here is the code:

```
Dim varItem As Variant

For Each varItem In Me!Lst_CPList.ItemsSelected
Debug.Print Lst_CPList.Column(2, varItem)
Next varItem
```

I can see in the immediate window that I am getting the right results. What I need to do is:

1 - compare the results from the above code (there will be as many results as selected rows in the listbox)

2 - make sure that the results are all the same. If they are not I will exit the sub and prompt the user make a selection with equal values in the third column of the listbox.

I hope this is sufficiently clear, thanks everyone for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one difference is enough to trigger the error, this is pretty straightforward.

```
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strValue As String
Dim strFirst As String

strFirst = ""
For Each varItem In Me!Lst_CPList.ItemsSelected
    strValue = Nz(Lst_CPList.Column(2, varItem), "")
    Debug.Print strValue

    ' First item? Then store for comparison
    If strFirst = "" Then
        strFirst = strValue
    ' Not first item: compare with first one
    Else
        If strValue <> strFirst Then
            MsgBox "Wrong pick!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

Next varItem
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, very helpful. I could not find some kind of guide to do this online so you have been very helpful. Solution worked just fine.